# I am really confused about finding poles of certain complex functions.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

There are certain complex functions which lack a proper denominator corresponding to which poles can be found for the given function. For example , the gaussian function, the frenel functions are some of the popular functions lacking any denominator, in the complex plane . So , as a result of those function lacking any pole , I am wondering how to evaluate their corresponding improper integrals using contour integration (complex analysis). Is there any way by which a denominator can be generated assuming certain conditions for those functions lacking denominator? I really want to clear the doubt regarding this ...All of yours opinions would be highly appreciabble in my regard. Thanks a lot in advance .

Comment: I don't see a need to worry about poles or denominators. IMO, poles make things more difficult. As long as you construct a contour such that divergence never comes into play and that it somehow helps you evaluate whatever you need to evaluate, you can be as creative as you want.

Comment: @Accelerator Can you please explain taking the gaussian integral as an example .

Comment: https://youtu.be/aw9BfO0Whic

Comment: @Accelerator Yes I have posted my doubt after watching that video (by qncubed3) only. In the video he generates a periodic denominator and integrates the generated auxiliary function over the box contour such that the when the auxiliary function is integrated along the real axis from - infinity to infinity , the required integral is restored . In this post of mine , I am just asking if the above mentioned method applies for any other function lacking a denominator or not .

Comment: Are you asking if it's always possible to integrate a function $f(z)$ using complex analysis by coming up with another function, $g(z)$, such that it's easy to find the poles of $g(z)$ and restore $f(z)$ somehow? If that's what you mean, then I don't know.

Comment: @Accelerator Yes, exactly it's the thing I mean .

Comment: It's probably one of those things in math where you have to keep throwing mud at the wall until something sticks.

Comment: @Accelerator True but I was actually curious to know whether we can consider the above method as a general algorithm to approach integrals lacking denominators .

Comment: I don't know either. What's wrong with things "lacking denominators"? In fact, the denominator thing you keep mentioning doesn't really make sense because any expression inherently has a denominator, namely $1$. If anything, poles make things more difficult because you would still need to bother with calculating the residues at those poles. Whereas if you don't have poles, then you could probably make a contour where your function is holomorphic on and inside it and set the sum of all the integrals equal to $0$ instead of $2\pi i \sum \text{residues}$.

Comment: @Accelerator Ok...I got it now.

Comment: @Accelerator Thanks a lot for your continuous support and opinions that helped me clarify my doubts

Comment: Yeah, no problem. I'm glad I was able to contribute. :)

Comment: @Accelerator One more clarification . If the absence of denominator really doesn't affect the evaluation of such integrals , then why did the person in the youtube video labor extra in generating a denominator to the gaussian function ?

Comment: Probably to show off for YouTube content.

Comment: @Accelerator Lol...but it is also a great approach though.Thanks .